# why is the fb.event not fired?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to trigger the FB subscribe event, but the alert does not work. 
The FB like button displays but when I click the like button there is no alert:

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="facebook.aspx.cs" Inherits="iFrame.facebook" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=&amp;href=www.goal.com"
            scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 47px;
            height: 20px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">


    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function (response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using the XFBML version of the Like button or else the event isn't detectable.

If the Javascript SDK didn't initialise the Like button then it also won't have access to the event fired. Use the XFBML version of the Like button instead of the iframe version and the rest of your code should work - it looks fine.

Comment: Go here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - when getting the code for your like button chose 'xfbml' instead of choosing 'iframe'